# Opening chrome extension using a link

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to open a chrome extension using a link or programmatically?  I want to give an option to users within my application to open the extension in a new chrome window and if possible open a URL on that tab.

Eg: I have an "Analyze Site" button in my application. When user clicks on it, I want to open a new browser window with url - http://www.example.net and open the extension "Analyze" on that window. The extension is developed by me as well in case any change in extension is required to achieve this.

Comment: open the "Analyze" extension ... why do you want to open it? extension are in the browser itself, and then already loaded. Or maybe I do not understand well, you need gui for user option or other , simply open your extension page with this uri : chrome://myexentions/your_html_file for example.

Comment: Neither chrome:// nor chrome-extension:// protocol can be used in web pages so your options are either provide an inline installation if the extension is not yet installed (see the documentation) or use a content script of your extension to intercept the click on that link and show the extension UI.